# Porting qmake to cmake with pro2cmake.py

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, qmake

I have a small C++ program that I am trying to move from qmake to cmake for ROS compatibility. Here is my .pro file:

```
QT       += core network websockets

QT       -= gui

TARGET = SampleApplication
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
           file1.cpp \
           file2.cpp \
           file3.cpp

HEADERS += \
           file1.h \
           file2.h \
    file3.h
```

After running the pro2cmake.py script on my .pro file here is the result:

```
#####################################################################
## SampleApplication Binary:
#####################################################################

qt_internal_add_executable(SampleApplication
    SOURCES
        main.cpp
        file1.cpp file1.h
        file2.cpp file2.h
        file3.cpp file3.h
    PUBLIC_LIBRARIES
        Qt::Network
        Qt::WebSockets
)

#### Keys ignored in scope 1:.:.:SampleApplication.pro:<TRUE>:
# TEMPLATE = "app"
```

I am unsure what to do with the result from the script since I cannot add qt_internal_add_executable to my CMakeList. Any advice is appreciated because I am unfamiliar with configuration and build files.

Comment: Also my files aren't actually named file1, file2, file3 btw. Just to hide info

Comment: What version of Qt, CMake, etc. are you using?

Comment: I am using Qt 5.9.5, qmake version 3.1 and cmake version 3.10.2